# How to show Percentage Icon rather Percent value

Tags: ui

Currently my app shows the percent value as 33%. But I would like to show the same with Icons by using Icon Sets on my **Standard Layout Page**.

Please suggest me some tips.

Comment: Do you have individual images? Or are you looking for a CSS backround-image based solution where the relevant part of a single image is presented?

Comment: It would be great if we are able to handle with CSS.. But this customization i am mainly looking on the standered layout.

Comment: Then I think you will have to take the approach @Bachovski suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you can generate 100 images to represent the values from 0 to 100% and put them in a static resource bundle. Then use a formula field that will pull up the correct image from the static resource bundle based on the value in your percentage field:

```
IMAGE("/resource/yourresourceID/" + Percentage_Field__c + ".png", "text")
```

Where `Percentage_Field__c` will have the values from 0 to 100.

I haven't tested this so try with a few images only to see if it's going to work.